# Cordova CLI Phone Gap Application navigator.app.exit Function not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am New Cordova phoneGap Development .i am impliment Simple Cordova Helloworld example it is working fine and also backbutton click Navigator.app.exit working fine.i include some code in My MainActivity After That Navigator.app.exit funtion not call on button click as well back press.
Please Give Me Some Suggestion Thank You.

```
    public class CordovaApp extends CordovaActivity implements   
   CordovaInterface {
  CordovaWebView cwv;
  private final ExecutorService threadPool =  
  Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  private CordovaPlugin activityResultCallback;
  public static final String PASSKEY = "s407iejl";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    //super.appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    MyClass mc = new MyClass(this, appView);
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(mc, "MyCls");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.buyView);      
    cwv.loadUrl(this.launchUrl);
     }




  @Override
  public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin command, Intent intent, 
         int requestCode) {
    this.activityResultCallback = command;

    // Start activity
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}

  @Override
  public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin plugin) {
    this.activityResultCallback = plugin;
  }

  @Override
  public Activity getActivity() {
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
    try {
        URI uri = new URI(data.toString());
        if (uri.toString().contains("http://asdf.com/proces?
             param=")) {

            String encryptedText = uri.getQuery().split("=")[1];
            JSONObject jObj = DecryptData.getDecryptedJson(encryptedText,
          PASSKEY);
            Log.i("CordovaApp", jObj.get("msg").toString());
            Log.i("CordovaApp", jObj.get("trxid").toString());
            cwv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/payment_status.htm? 
       resparam="+encryptedText);
        }
    } catch (Exception use) {
    }
    return null;
   }

  @Override
  public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
    return threadPool;

  }

 @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int 
   resultCode,  final Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    CordovaPlugin callback = this.activityResultCallback;
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please Give Me some Suggestion